# Xamarin.Forms.WebView based editors failing on Android 13 only

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, rich-text-editor

Calling all Xamarin-Android gurus - this issue is way over my head.

I have a Google Play App Store product in beta testing that is experiencing catastrophic, repeatable, data-loss inducing failures related to `Xamarin.Forms.WebView` on **Android 13 only**. Feel free to [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue.git) my minimal reproducible example project with separate branches for `Telerik.RadRichTextEditor` and the `Syncfusion.SfRichTextEditor`. As I understand it, both components wrap the `WebView` which in turn wraps javascript calls to the native `Android` control.

I do want to emphasize that this has worked for a long while on Android 12 physical devices with no issues. The iOS project also shows no sign of trouble.

---

The testbench is simple: the single page has an editor on it, and we load some html into that editor.

Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:tkrtf="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.RichTextEditor;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.RichTextEditor"
             x:Class="reproduce_android_13_webview_issue.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <tkrtf:RadRichTextEditor x:Name="rteditor"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

C#

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // rteditor.Source = TestHtml01; // PASS
    rteditor.Source = TestHtml02; // FAIL
}
```

---

The issue occurs when control is tapped and the soft keyboard opens. Whether it works or not depends on the html.

The first html source behaves *correctly* when the editor is tapped at the end of the text to set the cursor and start editing.

```
public const string TestHtml01 =
@"<html>
    <body>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sagittis ante id eros aliquet faucibus.</p>
        <p>Lore mi'ps umdol or si tame tc onse ct ETU etur adi piscinge lita liqu ams agitt is a NteIderOsew aliq ue.</p>
    </body>
</html>";
```

[image: telerik-pass]
[log-pass-telerik.txt](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/blob/telerik/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/logs/log-pass-telerik.txt)

---

However, add just one character to the end of the html and *the entire document is erased* as the WebView attempts to scroll to the character position.

[image: telerik fail]

```
// In this source, a single character is added at the end of paragraph 2.
public const string TestHtml02 =
@"<html>
    <body>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sagittis ante id eros aliquet faucibus.</p>
        <p>Lore mi'ps umdol or si tame tc onse ct ETU etur adi piscinge lita liqu ams agitt is a NteIderOsew aliq uet.</p>
    </body>
</html>";
```

[log-fail-telerik.txt](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/blob/telerik/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/logs/log-fail-telerik.txt)

I should also mention that even though the first html source opened up correctly at the start, attempting to actually edit the text produces erratic distortions in the document.

---

**SfRichTextEditor (comparison)**

With the `SfRichTextEditor`, the first html source still behaves normally. The html with the extra character still alters (but doesn't destroy) the document data. (There seems to be a different default stylesheet judging from the leading whitespace. Having "some" differences doesn't seem too surprising in light of that.)

[image: syncfusion fail]

[log-fail-syncfusion.txt](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/blob/telerik/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/logs/log-fail-syncfusion.txt)

[log-pass-syncfusion.txt](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/blob/telerik/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/reproduce-android-13-webview-issue/logs/log-pass-syncfusion.txt)

---

I don't know what's happening here and am hoping that someone with knowledge of the internals can offer a solution, workaround or at least an explanation. For me, speculating,  it *smells* like the WebView is attempting to ScrollToPosition when the soft input opens and the height changes. Perhaps there is some string measurement where the character index can be converted to view port coordinates. My rationale is that I ruled out the *length* of the text as the problem. The thing is, I can just change the upper case 'ETU' in the failing source to a lower-case 'etu' and then it passes. To me this seems as though the lower case is *narrower* in the proportional font and this makes a difference even though the character count has *not* changed. Anyway, it took me days to get this isolated and I'm pretty desperate for some insight if you have any.

Comment: I imagine both of those vendors would be interested in seeing this test case. Might be more effective to get one of them to look into this. I understand the fact that both fail means it isn't their code, but they presumably have an interest in xamarin webview continuing to work in Android 13. And may have knowledgeable people with deeper insight into what is happening, and whether there is any workaround that either they or you can do.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve good suggestion, will pursue. I'm a wee bit cynical tho' cuz I used to maintain a paid support license. Consider this verbatim response from one of my tickets: _"The issue with Focused/Unfocused methods, Focus, Unfocus events is the same. **The behavior comes from the WebView control. We have tried to find a workaround for both issues but without a success.**_" It sure seems worth floating it out here on SO - you're one of _many_ super-smart people I've met here and my impression is that I may have a more direct line to the persons actually writing the platform code _here_!

Comment: Absolutely agree. Pursue all avenues. At least now you know the vendor did attempt, and is aware of the issue. At this point, vendors main focus is "is this still an issue in Maui, or in .Net platform code (as appropriate)?" I suspect this one is, but I'm not using embedded webview, so have not been tracking that in Maui. It might be worth your time to do the Maui test, report it to `github maui issues` if needed. Hopefully get fixed before you need to switch over. (Though the number of backlogged issues is a concern to me.)

Comment: Just discovered that someone else logged [#15701](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15701) against `Xamarin.Forms` in a very different context but sure looks like the same behavior to me.  I reproduced their bug on my **Android 13** physical device and "not-reproduced" it on my **Android 12**. This gave some confidence in this being real so I added [#15708](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15708).

Comment: Note: It probably won't get fixed, unless you make a test `Maui` app, and reproduce the behavior in Maui's WebView. Should be identical to Xamarin's, just using Maui namespace. (Not BlazorWebView, that is something else.)

Comment: Vendor support was able to reproduce the bug! They tried it at first on a Pixel emulator and couldn't get it to fail (neither could I on an emulator) but took the extra step of trying a physical **Android 13** device and there it was. Indicators are now pointing toward `HybridWebView` and the layers beneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android 13 physical device used for testing performed an automatic software update on Mar 26 2023 and installed One UI version 5.1 which seems to have addressed the issue with `WebView` and `HybridWebView`.

To echo the excellent comment by ToolmakerSteve, "pursue all avenues". One way or another (whether or not I made any difference making noise about it) awareness of the problem was raised to the point that it got fixed at the OS level.